# Kendo UI MVC Client Template with Conditions not working

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.isCurrentlyLocked)
      .ClientTemplate("# if (isCurrentlyLocked && roles != 'Admin') { #"
      + "<input type='button' onclick='user_unlock' value='Unlock' class='k-button' />"
      + "# } else if(!isCurrentlyLocked && roles != 'Admin') {#"
      + "<input type='button' onclick='user_lock' value='Lock' class='k-button' />"
      + "#}#");
   columns.Template(p => p.roles).ClientTemplate("# if (roles != 'Admin') { #"
      + "<input type='button' onclick='user_delete' value='Delete' class='k-button' />"
      + "# }#");
```

I can't call my Javascript Functions `user_unlock`, `user_lock` or `user_delete`. The Server generates Html like `onclick=\u0027user_delete\u0027`. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try as follow:-

```
columns.Template(p => p.roles).ClientTemplate("# if (roles != \"Admin\") { #"
      + "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"user_delete()\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"k-button\" />"
      + "# }#");
```

Comment: kindly accpt the aswner for future ref @Fruity84